# Color discrete map messes up alignment of blocks in plotly timeline

Tags: express, colors, plotly, timeline

I have a plotly timeline with three blocks. They are nicely aligned when I don't color them.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        'y': [2,3,4],
        'van': [pd.Timestamp("2023-08-07 09:00"), pd.Timestamp("2023-08-07 14:30"), pd.Timestamp("2023-08-07 17:00")],
        'tot': [pd.Timestamp("2023-08-07 17:00"), pd.Timestamp("2023-08-07 22:30"), pd.Timestamp("2023-08-08 01:00")],
        'selected': [False, True, False]
    }
)

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start='van', x_end='tot', y='y',
                           color= "selected",
                           color_discrete_map = {True: "#CDCDD3", False: "#8C8C8F"},
                           )
fig.show()
```

This yields the following nice plot:

[image]

However, now I try to color them using color_discrete_map, like this:

```
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start='van', x_end='tot', y='y',
                           color= "selected",
                           color_discrete_map = {True: "#CDCDD3", False: "#8C8C8F"},
                           )
fig.show()
```

Then the plot is strangely messed up:
[image]

Anyone who knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be happening when you use the `color= "selected"` argument and there is more than one possible color – as far as I can tell, this is a bug (if I have time, I'll file a bug report).

To get around this, you can create the fig without using the color argument, which will set `fig.data` to be a tuple of one `go.Bar` object where all of the bars the same default plotly color. Then we can manually assign marker colors to the go.Bar object using the desired color mapping.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        'y': [2,3,4],
        'van': [pd.Timestamp("2023-08-07 09:00"), pd.Timestamp("2023-08-07 14:30"), pd.Timestamp("2023-08-07 17:00")],
        'tot': [pd.Timestamp("2023-08-07 17:00"), pd.Timestamp("2023-08-07 22:30"), pd.Timestamp("2023-08-08 01:00")],
        'selected': [False, True, False]
    }
)

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start='van', x_end='tot', y='y',)

## the fig is one go.Bar object
color_discrete_map = {True: "#CDCDD3", False: "#8C8C8F"}
colors = [color_discrete_map[s] for s in df['selected']]
fig.data[0]['marker'] = {'color': colors}
                           
fig.show()
```

[image]